# Ionic 2 error opening ws message

Tags: android, web-services, http, ionic-framework, android-emulator

I am getting an error, when I run my Ionic 2 project on an android emulator.

On the browser, all is working properly, but when I make an Http request from the emulator I have this error in my console:

[03:01:06]  error opening ws message: {"category":"console","type":"log","data":["test","1234"]}

what is happening?

I am using Storage provider too.

Let me know if you need some extra info.